# How to speed up slow suggestions in PyCharm?

Tags: macos, performance, autocomplete, pycharm

After update to PyCharm Pro 2020.01.02 I spotted a significant regress of speed of completion. Sometimes it works well, the same as before update, but sometimes it`s too slow. Maybe someone faced the same issue and knows how to solve it? My OS is Mac OS 10.15.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just contacted support: apparently this is a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2475) caused by a newer Java runtime. There's a [workaround here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2475#focus=streamItem-27-4181537.0-0) which I'll reproduce below:

1. **Install the "Choose Runtime" plugin**. Go to Preferences (⌘,) -> Plugins, search marketplace for "Choose Runtime".
2. **Open the Choose Runtime dialog**. Open "Find Action..." (⇧⌘A), search for "Choose Runtime..."
3. **Change your runtime to jbrsdk-11_0_6-osx-x64-b765.40.tar.gz**. That's what the workaround recommends but I was able to get good results choosing a more recent one.